# Calculate beta distribution confidence intervals efficiently

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I'm working with a really large data set where I need to calculate the confidence interval of a beta distribution created using each data point. I started by using the ppf function from scipy.stats.beta, but the computation time is just too long. Is there a more efficient way of calculating a beta distribution's confidence interval? A solution in python would be preferable, but a solution in another language that can be used in conjunction with python would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Have you got any inkling as to why its slow? It might be IO bound, memory-choked, or CPU bound.

Comment: The data sets I'm operating on have around 1,000,000 points in them, so I think the process of calculating that many confidence intervals is just very expensive.

Comment: On my laptop, which is not the fastest thing on earth, `stats.beta.ppf(0.9, np.random.random(1000000), np.random.random(1000000))` takes about twelve seconds. You are probably looking for something else, so it's best if you edit it into your answer.